# How to delete all rows from table except 6 given known uuids with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

I want to clean a table and only keep 6 rows targeted with uuids

```
DELETE FROM user WHERE user_id!='2536466f-38d0-4e81-acda-2e411fdb3030'
AND user_id!='cefc6515-e4a4-460c-9fb2-eb883037ff9e'
AND user_id!='479acacf-3914-485f-958c-51sfe77e6beb'
AND user_id!='7436a5a6-1361-42df-81a3-63007afcb835'
AND user_id!='373d4006-2f91-470f-b256-195fsd5835e9'
AND user_id!='aaff2a33-2a75-4e65-a7re-658cb38e6549'
```

I also tried this variation without success:

```
DELETE FROM user WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT FROM user WHERE user_id!='2536466f-38d0-4e81-acda-2e411fdb3030'
AND user_id!='cefc6515-e4a4-460c-9fb2-eb883037ff9e'
AND user_id!='479acacf-3914-485f-958c-51sfe77e6beb'
AND user_id!='7436a5a6-1361-42df-81a3-63007afcb835'
AND user_id!='373d4006-2f91-470f-b256-195fsd5835e9'
AND user_id!='aaff2a33-2a75-4e65-a7re-658cb38e6549'
    )
```

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: DELETE FROM user WHERE user_id NOT IN('a','b','c');

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: Several of your identifiers are not valid hexadecimal strings (s and r are not hex digits). Otherwise your first query should have worked (as long as none are null.) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=45a9e61a47a6d2b25b4b1bf56dc9101d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NOT IN`.

The `AND` in your `WHERE` clause doesn't work as the uuids can be at the same time in all rows.

```
DELETE FROM user 
WHERE  user_id NOT IN (
    '2536466f-38d0-4e81-acda-2e411fdb3030' ,
    'cefc6515-e4a4-460c-9fb2-eb883037ff9e' ,
    '479acacf-3914-485f-958c-51sfe77e6beb' ,
    '7436a5a6-1361-42df-81a3-63007afcb835' ,
    '373d4006-2f91-470f-b256-195fsd5835e9' ,
    'aaff2a33-2a75-4e65-a7re-658cb38e6549'
) ;
```